# http get request works in browser but failed in curl or postman

Tags: rest, http, curl, browser, postman

that's a serverless api running on remote cloud .

It works in browser but failed in curl/postman with error:
curl: (55) Send failure: Connection was aborted

when I can tried to copy request as curl in chrome browser， then paste to cmd, it still failed.
that means I still failed in curl even use the same request headers in browser.

looks like api-gateway or firewall on cloud blocked the requests from curl/postman but it allowed browser, anyone please can help me for understanding the different of the requests between browser and curl/postman?
thanks

Comment: Please, include the curl line into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out the issue was caused by Symantec endpoint protection installed on my PC, it blocked the request since the domain was not contained in company‘s access rule list. however SEP configured the special pass for browsers, so that's why it works in browser but failed in other ways.
Disable SEP then issue gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the large header size in the copied request. See https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/11405

The "Copy as Curl" in Browser Developer Options (under Network), copies all the headers browser has added such as *sec-**, *x-client-data*, etc. Try removing these headers added by the browser, and run the Curl command again.

Comment: Thanks for the response, looks like it was not related to the headers of the reuqest, there's no such sec-*, x-client-data headers in browser request, the request was quite simple. 
There's api-gateway or firewall in frond of cloud infrastructure, it blocked my network,  when I used company network, it failed in postman/curl , succeed in browser.  but when I used other network(like home network), it's working for all tools..  that's weird since I don't know there's any cloud compoents that can distinguish different kind of network?  
thanks again..